# handle multiple conditions on a string

Tags: javascript

I've created a function which takes a string and replace it's ending substring, so if the string ends with `AddFiche`, `EditFiche` or Fiche they should be replaced with `Liste`, and some other conditions this is what I tried:

```
function _getParentComponent(component){
    if(component.endsWith('AddFiche')){
        return component.replace('AddFiche', 'Liste');
    }else if(component.endsWith('EditFiche')){
        return component.replace('EditFiche', 'Liste');
    }else if(component.endsWith('Fiche')){
        return component.replace('Fiche', 'Liste');
    }else if(component === "selection"){
        if($rootRouter._outlet.previousInstruction.componentType === "import"){
            return "import";
        }
    }else if(component === "result"){
        if($rootRouter._outlet.previousInstruction.componentType === "selection"){
            return "import";
        }
    }else if(component.startsWith("request")){
        if($rootRouter._outlet.previousInstruction.componentType === "dynamicRouting"){
            return "dynamicRouting";
        }
    }else{
        return component;
    }
}
```

As you can see there are a lot of if elses, isn't there any other way to do this ? since I might add other conditions later, and the code looks ugly with all those if elses.

Comment: It is very difficult to suggest an alternative if you don't give us any hint at to why you are doing this. I could try to guess, but should I? If I did I would suggest to remember the parent in the component, then you don't have to have these elses at all, because you know.

Comment: I would probably build an array of replacements. It's gonna be a bit tricky because you got two kinds of replacements (total and ending), but maybe you can declare them in a regex syntax. You could then simply walk the array and do each of the replacements using [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware in my database I have route names stored in a table, these route names can end with `Fiche`, `AddFiche`, `EditFiche`, `Liste` or something else, the routes that are ending with `Fiche`, `AddFiche`, `EditFiche` they have the same name as their parent route followed by `Liste`, so: `someFiche` has a parent that called `someListe`, and `someAddFiche` has a parent `someListe` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var replaces = [{
    match: 'AddFiche',
    replace: 'Liste'
  },
  {
    match: 'EditFiche',
    replace: 'Liste'
  },
  {
    match: 'Fiche',
    replace: 'Liste'
  }
]

function _getParentComponent(component) {
  var done = false;
  for (var r of replaces) {
    if (component.endsWith(r.match)) {
      return component.replace(r.match, r.replace);
    }
  }
  if (component === "selection") {
    if ($rootRouter._outlet.previousInstruction.componentType === "import") {
      return "import";
    }
  } else if (component === "result") {
    if ($rootRouter._outlet.previousInstruction.componentType === "selection") {
      return "import";
    }
  } else if (component.startsWith("request")) {
    if ($rootRouter._outlet.previousInstruction.componentType === "dynamicRouting") {
      return "dynamicRouting";
    }
  } else {
    return component;
  }
}
console.log("Input: LoremIpsumFiche");
console.log("Output:",_getParentComponent("LoremIpsumFiche"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be this

```js
var ends = ['One', 'Two', 'Wood'];
var words = ['LOne', 'ROnes', 'Two2', 'TwoTwo', 'No Wood', 'Woodless'];
var replaced = "REPLACED";

for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < ends.length; j++) {
    if(words[i].endsWith(ends[j])) {
      words[i] = words[i].replace(new RegExp(ends[j] + '$'), replaced);
      break;
    }
  }
}

console.log(words);
```